# Trouble getting simple POST from Objective C to PHP working

Tags: php, objective-c, post

I'm a total newbie at PHP, but this seems so simple, there doesn't seem like any way for me to be screwing this up, unless I'm COMPLETELY misunderstanding the way all of this works.

Objective-C:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com"]];
[request setPostValue:@"test value A" forKey:@"testA"];
[request setPostValue:@"test value B" forKey:@"testB"];
[request setDelegate:self.delegate];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $testValueA = $_POST['testA'];
    $testValueB = $_POST['testB'];

    echo "Value A = $testValueA, Value B = $testValueB";
?>
```

When I `NSLog` the return string from the `request`, I get `Value A = Value B =` . Is this an error in my poorly understood PHP implementation, or is there an issue with the Objective-C?

### --EDIT--

`print_r($_POST)`, `var_dump($_POST)`, and `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` all return nothing. So I'm assuming that the problem lies in `ASIFormDataRequest`?

### --EDIT 2--

Dumped the headers from the response:

```
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Thu, 04 Nov 2010 20:05:39 GMT";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=2, max=199";
Server = Apache;
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.2.14";
```

Not sure what to do with this info.

### --Edit 3--

Getting this log message from the error file:

```
"(Notice) Undefined index: testA"
```

Also one for `testB`

Comment: The PHP end looks fine. Can't judge on the Objective-C end. You could try a `print_r($_POST);` to check whether the data is sent in a different form somehow

Comment: Have you tried dumping the whole of $_POST using var_dump? Alternatively have you tried using GET to see if the connection is the issue?

Comment: Also try whether `echo $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;` outputs anything

Comment: updated question. Short answer, all 3 returned nothing.

Comment: Might be useful to dump all the headers in the response and see what pops up... it all looks fine from here, but maybe there is an encoding issue or something.

Comment: Updated the question with the dumped headers

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error log for apache?  I have similar code on the Objective-C and PHP side (using ASIHTTP) that works fine.

Comment: updated with the errors from the PHP error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there was a redirect going on without my knowledge (From `http://www.mysite.com` to `http://www.mysite.com/`), and was losing the POST data there. Thanks to everyone for trying to help debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with C, but try changing

```
echo "Value A = $testValueA, Value B = $testValueB";
```

to

```
echo "Value A = " . $testValueA . ", Value B = " . $testValueB;
```

Comment: Nope, both variants will work. It would be different if single quotes `'` were used

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, does the Obj-C request need a "send" message or something? Usually in OOP you create something and then you tell it act. Maybe that's what's missing.

Comment: Nope, the [request startAsynchronous] sends the request.

Answer (score 0):

Also depends on how PHP is executed on server (via CGI or Apache handler).
In case it's CGI, you could try this:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents(STDIN);
parse_str($data, $_POST);
// ... your code
```

Comment: Generates a warning now: `Warning: file_get_contents(STDIN) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [my site] on line 2`

Comment: OK, could you debug your C program by pointing it to http://127.0.0.1 and listening on 80 port on your local machine (with netcat for example)? We'll see what it is sending at least :-)

Comment: Here's what ASIHTTPRequest says it's sending:`==== Building an application/x-www-form-urlencoded body ====
testA=Test&testB=
==== End of application/x-www-form-urlencoded body ====`

Comment: 'testB' is sent empty? You should try to capture real request on the server's side, with netcat on localhost as I proposed earlier or http-packet capturer like ServiceCapture, or with WireShark.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put anything in for that variable. testB isn't sent empty if I feed it a value.  I am also having trouble getting ASIHTTPRequest to make the request to my local IP as opposed to the remote server. It's bouncing back. Not sure what I need to open on my mac to allow me to do this.

Comment: On Mac, try running "nc -l -p 80" from console. Then run your program (pointed to http://127.0.0.1:80/), and you should see its request in console.

Comment: No, that returns an error from ASIHTTPRequest: "Unable to start HTTP connection"